# create a new button to clear all fields except one using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-web-components, aura

I am new to development have started coding now and learning as per each requirement i am able to take.

I have  a requirement where "Today on all 4 pages within the community we only have a submit button. The new ask is to introduce a "Clear" button that once selected it would clear out any of the fields populated on the page. THIS SHOULD NOT CLEAR THE CUSTOMER NUMBER FIELD "

There is a lightning component with 4 Pages and they all have a submit button. Now the business needs a Clear button to clear all the fields except for the Customer Number field.

Snippet of the code shown below on Aura Component

```xml
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" Controller = "EnterTrackingNumberHttpCallOut"> 
    <aura:attribute name="response" type="Map"/>
    <aura:attribute name="returnData" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ListOfAttributes" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name = "trackingNumber" type = "integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name = "CustomerNumber" type = "integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    
    <!--aura handler with waiting and donewaiting events-->
    <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <!--loading spinner start-->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner == true}">
        <c:Utility_spinner />
    </aura:if>
    <!-- Loading spinner end-->
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.isRefreshed}"/>
    <div class="slds-box slds-align_absolute-center">
        <!--Header Part-->
        <div class="slds-media__body">
            <p class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Tracking Number Request">Tracking Number Request</p>             
        </div> 
    </div>
    <br/>
    <!--Header part close -->     
     <div style="height:50px; width:200px">          
        <lightning:input type="text" id="CustomerNumber" name = "CustomerNumber" label = "CustomerNumber"  disabled="true" value = "{!v.CustomerNumber}"/>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div style="height:50px; width:200px" >          
        <lightning:input type="text" id="trackingNumber" name = "trackingNumber" label ="Tracking Number(USPS, UPS, FedEx..)" required = "true" value = "{!v.trackingNumber}"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="slds-form-element">
         <lightning:button class="customButton" label = "Submit" onclick="{!c.getTrackNumber}" />
{New code to be implemented below I guess}
    </div>
    <br/> 
    <br/> 
    <h3 class="slds-section--title">RESULT : </h3><br />
    <div style="width:400px;height:400px;">
        {!v.response}
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

The code above has the submit button created which is highlighted in bold. We have another 3 pages similar to this. If someone can show me on this page i can implement the same for the rest of the 3 pages.

Any help for this will be appreciated :) New to Development still getting there :)

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply clear the values of the attributes linked to the fields that you want to clear in the controller function linked to your new clear button. For the example code above, your clear button could look something like this:

```
<lightning:button class="customButton" label = "Clear" onclick="{!c.clearValues}" />
```

And your controller function could do this:

```
clearValues : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.trackingNumber", "");
}
```

This is achieved by the reactive nature of Lightning component Attributes, which propagate their values to all elements that reference it when they're set with a new value

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the reply. I dont see a controller added to the component but there are 2 other classes and i am not sure in which class to add. I am unable to add the class here as its big.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the JavaScript/client side controller in the Lightning component bundle (where the getTrackNumber function from the submit button should exist)

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. When i tried implementing as you mentioned above i got the below errors
Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier.
Invalid character in identifier: ,
Invalid type: component
Invalid type: helper
Invalid constructor name: function
Can you tell me what needs to be done? Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I think you might be adding the code to the Apex class rather than the JavaScript controller :). I highly recommend you go through this Trailhead module to get an overview on the Lightning/Aura Components: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics

Comment: You are right i wrote in a different controller. I just learnt that in LWC there a 2 controllers one on the server side and client side. Thanks a lot for this.